# centerPopUp centers the popUp but with delay

Tags: apache-flex, popup

did someone else encounter this problem?
I use the methods PopUpManager.createPopUp() and PopUpManager.centerPopUp()
to create and center a pop up window but it looks strange,
like the window is created at (0,0) and then reappears in the middle of the screen.
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a smoother appearance, instantiate the thing you want to show ahead of time, then add it with PopUpManager.addPopUp and center it with PopUpManager.centerPopUp.

```
var popup:MyPopup = new MyPopup();
PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup, this);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp();
```